# Problem using Vim-LaTeX on my Mac

Tags: vim

I installed Vim-LaTeX-1.10.0 (per the install instructions on SorceForge) in `/Users/tom/.vim` and configured `.vimrc` per the instructions.

After starting `mvim` (or `vim`), I tried entering: `helptags ~/.vim/doc` per the instructions, and get: `E151: No match: /Users/tom/.vim/doc/**`

There was no `doc` folder under `/Users/tom/.vim`, so I created one but that didn't help either.

Comment: Try using a package manager and/or cloning the github repository: https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex

Comment: If you don't have a package manager for vim, try [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) (recommended!), [vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) or [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen)